# VSCode Command Palette (Ctrl + Shift + P) keyboard shortcut isn't working on new installation

Tags: visual-studio-code, binding, keyboard, key, keyboard-shortcuts

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> in VSCode (shortcut for "Command Palette") nothing happens.

Side note: I've *just* installed VSCode on my new PC (Windows 10,) so it's a fresh installation if that helps (it works on my laptop.) This is unsettling since I can actually see Ctrl + Shift + P listed in the bindings table.

It's important! Since for the most part I use this command to habitually open files.

Now I understand it can be possibly caused by some other software, perhaps -- I'm looking into that (will post what I find, if I ever get it to work.)

If I can't figure it out, I'm simply going to rewire it (at least for now) in key bindings but it's not really what I want to do.

Meanwhile, is there any classic cases that can jam Command Palette, specific to new installation?

Comment: I struggled to assign a different hotkey to what you're calling "Command Palette".  It seems that it's now called "Show All Commands".

Answer (score 12):

For me, TickTick on the Mac had overtaken the Command+Shift+P. I disabled it in TickTick -> More -> Hotkeys and removing the global shortcut.

A more general way to remove conflicting shortcuts on MacOS:

1. choose Apple menu  > System settings, then click Keyboard  in the sidebar. (You may need to scroll down.)
2. Click Keyboard Shortcuts on the right. A warning icon appears next to conflicting keyboard shortcuts. Double-click the shortcut, then change it.

Answer (score 4):

This is an actual issue on [GitHub](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/12527) There is a good chance it's caused by other software which may be something like:

1. Password keychains
2. Screen capture
3. OBS
4. (Check any similar software you might use I can almost guarantee that one of the other apps is intercepting it globally. You said it's a new installation, so you probably installed other apps.)

To see all shortcuts or rebind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, then <kbd>K</kbd> as per this [edit keyboard shortcuts](https://semicolon.dev/tutorial/vscode/keyboard-shortcuts#add-or-modify-any-keyboard-shortcut) tutorial. Make sure Ctrl+Shift+P is on this list. **Another issue** that could cause this is your VSCode json settings file is read only or doesn't exist for some reason. A lot less likely, but still worth checking. Good luck with this.

Comment: Also AutoHotkey scripts (something I'd set up a long time ago and forgotten about )

Comment: you can also use `F1` for the command palette instead of `Ctrl+Shift+P`

Comment: This happened to me with a Razer Cortex update for a mouse I have, I disabled it in the Razer Cortex settings: Settings > Hotkeys > Timer

Comment: TagSpaces it was for me. Why would they register global callbacks? If you're a developer, just don't.

Answer (score 3):

Razer Cortex after the last update started to intercept <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> and other keybindings. I've turned it off and it helps, but you can try to change those keybindings in the Cortex settings if that's what causing the problem in your case.

Answer (score 1):

it would be "ctrl + k + s" to see the command list, and yes F1 is the alternative to "Ctrl+shift+P" I also have Razer mouse and it seems to conflict.

Answer (score 1):

#### For Mac Users

In Mac had the same problem and realized that it occures after triggering Git Lense extention. A quick inspection on key bindings and disabling the non-default binding there solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On macOS, the application SPlayer ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaGyv.png)) steals the shortcuts <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> and <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>. For me, the solution was to close that program.